# Kakfa fails to start with Fatal error "Duplicate log directories found"

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera

Kafka fails to start with below error:

```
Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate log directories found: /node5/kafka/data/logs-47, /node7/kafka/data/logs-47!
    at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$loadLogs$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(LogManager.scala:155)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anon$1.run(CoreUtils.scala:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Kafka 0.9.0.1 is deployed as part of Cloudera.

What does the issue mean?

Is there a workaround or solution to this problem? Couldn't find it.

I reached this error after restart the broker following underreplicated partitions issue in some topic partition.

There were below errors in the broker's log before the restart

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Compaction for partition [logs,47] cannot be aborted and paused since it is in LogCleaningPaused state.
        at kafka.log.LogCleanerManager$$anonfun$abortAndPauseCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(LogCleanerManager.scala:149)
        at kafka.log.LogCleanerManager$$anonfun$abortAndPauseCleaning$1.apply(LogCleanerManager.scala:140)
        at kafka.log.LogCleanerManager$$anonfun$abortAndPauseCleaning$1.apply(LogCleanerManager.scala:140)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:231)
...
```

Cloudera Data Directories configuration:

```
/node/kafka/data
/node2/kafka/data
...
/node8/kafka/data
```

*UPDATE*

I've inspected duplicate directories contents and found that the newest directory seems to have empty log segments:

```
ls -l /node5/kafka/data/logs-47

-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka 10485760 Mar  9 05:35 00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka        0 Mar  8 13:12 00000000000000000000.log
```

While older folder is not:

```
ls /node7/kafka/data/logs-47

-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka 10485760 Mar  9 05:35 00000000000000366115.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka kafka        0 Nov 25 10:13 00000000000000366115.log
```

Comment: Well, what directories are on that broker for the Kafka topic data?

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Kafka stores data on disk. Please show the list of directories of that data

Comment: @OneCricketeer added the configuration from Cloudera. Hope it's what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is saying that you have more than one directory on a single broker that contains data from a topic named `logs` with at least 47 partitions.

The LogCleaner cannot continue to delete that data until it knows which one is the correct directory

If you have some idea about what should be in the topic, you can dump the log segments and inspect messages

If you don't know what data should be there, and the partitions are replicated to other brokers that are healthy, then delete all of the faulty partition directories and restart the broker, letting replication heal the missing data

Comment: Thanks, i've added more information to the question. Maybe i can delete just the folder containing empty log segment?

Comment: To fix the error, you'd have to delete one of the directories, not just the files. The fact that the log segments are empty seems like a separate issue